# How to get a4paper with package lettre?

Tags: pdf, paper-size, lettre

Using this example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{lettre}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Service des réclamations}
\nofax
\opening{Madame, Monsieur,}
\lipsum[3]
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Built with

```
latexmk -pdf -xelatex
```

I get a pdf with is not A4, but letter perhaps. However I mentionned `a4paper` on the `\documentclass` option.

What did I miss ?

**EDIT**

It seems I can get the correct pdf size with the following. So what should I include these two lines in addition to `a4paper`?

```
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
```

Comment: I get A4 with your MWE. This probably depends on the default paper size set for your TeX installation. Mine is A4 but yours may be US letter. The class is setting `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` correctly given the `a4paper` option. The problem is that this does not set the output paper size correctly for the driver, I think, but only sets it correctly for the logical layout, so to speak. So you get A4 layout on US letter 'physical' paper. Admittedly, the physical paper is electronic in this case. And the class can't simply set this because it depends on the engine.... Load `geometry` ?